# Delineating divs of large chunks of text with XPath (or other)

Tags: python, html, xpath, xhtml, lxml

Given a page such as [this](http://jobs.kelkoo.co.uk/), with two jobs (we'll ignore 'Open applications' for now) fully described one after the other, I'm looking for a reliable way of extracting the individual job specs. The first goal is to extract the specs, and then hopefully wrap them in some enclosing HTML tags so that they render in a browser when saved as a HTML file.

[image]

Obviously if I knew in advance that the class name for the top level div were called "jobitem", I could run a simple XPath like `//div[@class='jobitem']`

There will be several such sites though (with widely differing designs, but **all with full job specs listed one after the other**), and my program won't have the luxury of such class name knowledge in advance. One thing my program **will** know: the absolute and relative position of the job headings (`<h2>`, `<h3>` etc.). In other words, I'll be running a query like the following:

```
//*[self::h2 or self::h3 or self::h4][contains(., 'Country Manager')]
```

... resulting in an array of Python [lxml](http://lxml.de/) XPath objects, from which relative XPaths can then be performed. Perhaps this knowledge is a starting point for grabbing all text in between each heading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"... resulting in an array of Python lxml XPath objects, from which relative XPaths can then be performed. Perhaps this knowledge is a starting point for grabbing all text in between each heading?"*

Sure (if I understand this correctly), at this point the task is straightforward using `following-sibling` axis in the relative XPath :

```
following-sibling::div
```